# Process containing object method doesn't recognize edit to object

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have the following situation `process=Process(target=sample_object.run)` I then would like to edit a property of the sample_object: `sample_object.edit_property(some_other_object)`.

```
class sample_object:
       def __init__(self):
          self.storage=[]
       def edit_property(self,some_other_object):
          self.storage.append(some_other_object)
       def run:
          while True:
             if len(self.storage) is not 0:
                  print "1"
             #I know it's an infinite loop. It's just an example.
```

## _______________________________________________________

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from sample import sample_object
from sample2 import some_other_object
class driver:

      if __name__ == "__main__":
         samp = sample_object()
         proc = Process(target=samp.run)
         proc.start()
         while True:
           some = some_other_object()
           samp.edit_property(some)
           #I know it's an infinite loop
```

The previous code never prints "1". How would I connect the Process to the sample_object so that an edit made to the object whose method Process is calling is recognized by the process? In other words, is  there a way to get `.run` to recognize the change in `sample_object` ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`multiprocessing.Manager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) to share Python data structures between processes.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager


class A(object):

    def __init__(self, storage):
        self.storage = storage

    def add(self, item):
        self.storage.append(item)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.storage:
                print 1


if __name__ == '__main__':

    manager = Manager()
    storage = manager.list()

    a = A(storage)

    p = Process(target=a.run)
    p.start()

    for i in range(10):
        a.add({'id': i})

    p.join()
```

Comment: But what if another process was added that got the objects added to storage through reference and didn't access the storage at all. It then proceeded to make edits to the object from the storage it got through reference when it was instantiated. The process containing `a.run` doesn't recognize any of these changes.

Comment: I don't want the objects(processes) making the edits to have to take or get anything from the manager list. I want them to make the edits simply by getting a reference to the object it will make edits to in its constructor. The manager list will act as a storage for `a.run` to get from.